# Is it possible to run commands from a stored procedure in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to run commands from a stored procedure in Oracle?
I have a web-based client-server architecture; The server communicates with a database server holding oracle database, I want to enable the client to trigger the backup operation; i.e. the user on the client side just sends a command to the server which then directs it to the database server, where all the work is done automatically. The client has no oracle tools to establish the backup operation. I think the best solution is to create a stored procedure on the database server which backs up the database using the appropriate commands. Is that possible? and if so then how?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "backup"? You can initiate a dump through SQL using `dbms_datapump`. But I don't think you can actually start a real backup using rman through a SQL command.

Comment: You can submit a job that does the real backup though, can't you? Not sure why you'd want to do that on demand though - kind of implies you could have periods where no backups are being performed, which doesn't sound like a good idea. Hopefully you are referring to an export, but it really isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: Do you want to do something like http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_operating_system_os_command_oracle.htm